# How to convert my weirdly formatted dataset from long to wide?

Tags: stata

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Country | Year | Indicator 1 | Indicator 2 | Indicator 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | 1950 | 23.1 | 123.1 | 211 |
| Germany | 1951 | 24.1 | 125.1 | 217 |
| Germany | 1952 | 24.1 | 125.1 | 217 |
| Austria | 1950 | 24.1 | 125.1 | 217 |
| Austria | 1951 | 24.1 | 125.1 | 21123 |
| Austria | 1952 | 24.1 | 125.1 | 21123 |

I want to reshape it in Stata so it looks like this:

| Country | Indicators | 1950 | 1951 | 1952 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Germany | Indicator 1 | 23.1 | 123.1 | 211 |
| Germany | Indicator 2 | 24.1 | 125.1 | 217 |
| Germany | Indicator 3 | 24.1 | 125.1 | 217 |
| Austria | Indicator 1 | 24.1 | 125.1 | 217 |
| Austria | Indicator 2 | 24.1 | 125.1 | 21123 |
| Austria | Indicator 3 | 24.1 | 125.1 | 21123 |

Ignore the fake data here. How do I reshape like this in Stata?

If it's any help, I'm looking to export this to Excel.

Comment: You posted this on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/qzour9/urgent_help_needed_please/ and should also flag cross-posting here.

Answer (score 0):

From a Stata point of view, your layout is optimal and you are asking for a layout that is weird and almost no use, unless exceptionally some other software needs it.

Still, it can be done. Please note the use of `dataex` to show Stata data examples as code to input. Also, in Stata variable names can't start with integers.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str7 country int year float(indicator1 indicator2) int indicator3
"Germany" 1950 23.1 123.1   211
"Germany" 1951 24.1 125.1   217
"Germany" 1952 24.1 125.1   217
"Austria" 1950 24.1 125.1   217
"Austria" 1951 24.1 125.1 21123
"Austria" 1952 24.1 125.1 21123
end

. reshape long indicator, i(country year) j(which)
(j = 1 2 3)

Data                               Wide   ->   Long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of observations                6   ->   18          
Number of variables                   5   ->   4           
j variable (3 values)                     ->   which
xij variables:
       indicator1 indicator2 indicator3   ->   indicator
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. l

     +-----------------------------------+
     | country   year   which   indica~r |
     |-----------------------------------|
  1. | Austria   1950       1       24.1 |
  2. | Austria   1950       2      125.1 |
  3. | Austria   1950       3        217 |
  4. | Austria   1951       1       24.1 |
  5. | Austria   1951       2      125.1 |
     |-----------------------------------|
  6. | Austria   1951       3      21123 |
  7. | Austria   1952       1       24.1 |
  8. | Austria   1952       2      125.1 |
  9. | Austria   1952       3      21123 |
 10. | Germany   1950       1       23.1 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 11. | Germany   1950       2      123.1 |
 12. | Germany   1950       3        211 |
 13. | Germany   1951       1       24.1 |
 14. | Germany   1951       2      125.1 |
 15. | Germany   1951       3        217 |
     |-----------------------------------|
 16. | Germany   1952       1       24.1 |
 17. | Germany   1952       2      125.1 |
 18. | Germany   1952       3        217 |
     +-----------------------------------+

.  rename indicator y

. reshape wide y, i(country which) j(year)
(j = 1950 1951 1952)

Data                               Long   ->   Wide
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of observations               18   ->   6           
Number of variables                   4   ->   5           
j variable (3 values)              year   ->   (dropped)
xij variables:
                                      y   ->   y1950 y1951 y1952
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

 
. l, sepby(country)

     +-----------------------------------------+
     | country   which   y1950   y1951   y1952 |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. | Austria       1    24.1    24.1    24.1 |
  2. | Austria       2   125.1   125.1   125.1 |
  3. | Austria       3     217   21123   21123 |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  4. | Germany       1    23.1    24.1    24.1 |
  5. | Germany       2   123.1   125.1   125.1 |
  6. | Germany       3     211     217     217 |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you Nick! In this case, how can I have the entire indicator name under the "Which" column. So it would say "indicator_1" "indicator_2" etc under the "which" column.

Comment: What's the point of that? Sure,  you can go `gen WHICH = "indicator_" + strofreal(which)`.